# Twitter oAuth callbackUrl - localhost development

Tags: twitter, oauth

Is anyone else having a difficult time getting Twitters oAuth's callback URL to hit their localhost development environment.
Apparently it has been disabled recently. http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=534#c1

Does anyone have a workaround. I don't really want to stop my development

Comment: It worked for me by setting twitter callback url to my real website url. While testing in localhost -> twitter signup, redirected to localhost (instead of website url).

Answer (score 135):

**Alternative 1.**

Set up your .hosts (Windows) or etc/hosts file to point a live domain to your localhost IP. such as:

> `127.0.0.1` `xyz.example`

where `xyz.example` is your real domain.

**Alternative 2.**

Also, the article gives the tip to alternatively use a URL shortener service. Shorten your local URL and provide the result as callback.

**Alternative 3.**

Furthermore, it seems that it works to provide for example `http://127.0.0.1:8080` as callback to Twitter, instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Could this be causing the following error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized?

Comment: How does localhost work when there is no tunnel to it? It doesn't actually hit ur local machine?

Comment: @JackTuck The callback is called by the user's browser, not by Twitter's servers.

Answer (score 25):

I just had to do this last week. Apparently `localhost` doesn't work but `127.0.0.1` does Go figure.

This of course assumes that you are registering two apps with Twitter, one for your live `www.mysite.example` and another for `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 12):

Just put `http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/` as the callback URL, where `xxxx` is the port for your framework

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it was disabled because of the recent security issue that was found in OAuth. The only solution for now is to create two OAuth applications - one for production and one for development. In the development application you set your localhost callback URL instead of the live one.

Comment: I just tried doing that, but it doesn't accept http://localhost:3000/ as a URL format...

Comment: Yes, they seem to filter such URLs. :( But the support for custom callback urls is back - maybe they're supported there.

Answer (score 8):

Callback URL edited

```
http://localhost:8585/logintwitter.aspx
```

Convert to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8585/logintwitter.aspx
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how i did it:

Registered Callback URL:
http://127.0.0.1/Callback.aspx

```
   OAuthTokenResponse authorizationTokens = 
        OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(ConfigSettings.getConsumerKey(), 
                                     ConfigSettings.getConsumerSecret(), 
                                     "http://127.0.0.1:1066/Twitter/Callback.aspx");
```

ConfigSettings:

```
public static class ConfigSettings
{
    public static String getConsumerKey()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"].ToString();
    }

    public static String getConsumerSecret()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>

    <add key="ConsumerKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <add key="ConsumerSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

</appSettings>
```

Make sure you set the property 'use dynamic ports' of you project to 'false' and enter a static port number instead. (I used 1066).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Use http://smackaho.st

What it does is a simple DNS association to 127.0.0.1 which allows you to bypass the filters on localhost or 127.0.0.1 :

> smackaho.st.      28800   IN  A   127.0.0.1

So if you click on the link, it will display you what you have on your local webserver (and if you don't have one, you'll get a 404). You can of course set it to any page/port you want :

http://smackaho.st:54878/twitter/callback

Comment: smackaho.st is no longer available http://tbaggery.com/2010/03/04/smack-a-ho-st.html.  Use lvh.me instead.  It goes directly to localhost.

Answer (score 5):

I was working with Twitter callback url on my localhost. If you are not sure how to create a virtual host ( this is important ) use Ampps. He is really cool and easy. In a few steps you have your own virtual host and then every url will work on it. For example:

1. download and install ampps
2. Add new domain. ( here you can set for example twitter.local) that means your virtual host will be http://twitter.local and it will work after step 3.
3. I am working on Win so go under to your host file -> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and add line:    127.0.0.1       twitter.local

Restart your Ampps and you can use your callback. You can specify any url, even if you are using some framework MVC or you have htaccess url rewrite.

Hope This Help!
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  On linux, just add the development domain name to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 4):

Seems nowadays `http://127.0.0.1` also stopped working.
A simple solution is to use `http://localtest.me` instead of `http://localhost` it is always pointing to `127.0.0.1` And you can even add any arbitrary subdomain to it, and it will still point to `127.0.0.1`

See [Website](http://readme.localtest.me/)

Answer (score 3):

When I develop locally, I always set up a locally hosted dev name that reflects the project I'm working on. I set this up in xampp through xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and then also in \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

So if I am setting up a local dev site for example.com, I would set it up as example.dev in those two files.

**Short Answer:** Once this is set up properly, you can simply treat this url (http://example.dev) as if it were live (rather than local) as you set up your Twitter Application.

A similar answer was given here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5749

Direct Quote (emphasis added):

> You can provide any valid URL with a domain name we recognize on the
>   application details page. OAuth 1.0a requires you to send a
>   oauth_callback value on the request token step of the flow and *we'll
>   accept a **dynamic locahost-based callback** on that step*.

This worked like a charm for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done very conveniently with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler):

- Open menu **Tools > HOSTS...**
- Insert a line like `127.0.0.1 your-production-domain.com`, make sure that "Enable remapping of requests..." is checked. Don't forget to press <kbd>**Save**</kbd>.
- If access to your real production server is needed, simply exit Fiddler or disable remapping.
- Starting Fiddler again will turn on remapping (if it is checked).

A pleasant bonus is that you can specify a custom port, like this:
`127.0.0.1:3000 your-production-domain.com` (it would be impossible to achieve this via the hosts file). Also, instead of IP you can use any domain name (e.g., `localhost`).

This way, it is possible (but not necessary) to register your Twitter app only once (provided that you don't mind using the same keys for local development and production).

Answer (score 2):

edit this function on **TwitterAPIExchange.php** at line **#180**

```
public function performRequest($return = true)
{
    if (!is_bool($return)) 
    { 
        throw new Exception('performRequest parameter must be true or false'); 
    }

    $header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');

    $getfield = $this->getGetfield();
    $postfields = $this->getPostfields();

    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
    );

    if (!is_null($postfields))
    {
        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postfields;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($getfield !== '')
        {
            $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= $getfield;
        }
    }

    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $json = curl_exec($feed);
    curl_close($feed);

    if ($return) { return $json; }
}
```

Comment: You can download TwitterAPIExchange.php from here https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Answer (score 2):

I had the same challenge and I was not able to give localhost as a valid callback URL. So I created a simple domain to help us developers out:
https://tolocalhost.com

It will redirect any path to your localhost domain and port you need. Hope it can be of use to other developers.

Comment: Excellent resource, But your domain adds "/" to the end of url which leads to 404 on some occasions. could you please fix it? For example it redirects as "localhost/somename/?<response>, but it should be "localhost/somename?<response>

Comment: @Channa I tried to reproduce this but it seems that the script works correctly. What browser are you using? I tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox and it works like expected.

Comment: It happens to me in both Chrome and Firefox. This is the hostname I put in your page "http://localhost:8080/dashboard/twitterRedirect.jsp" But when it redirects it goes to "http://localhost:8080/dashboard/twitterRedirect.jsp/?oauth_token=qvlNawAAAAAA4VB-AAABYWVBa7Y&oauth_verifier=pIfZPI75mTBFNkbWDL6gZ83M9rpBmbnh" Please note the "/" symbol before the question mark. It will cause my app to send me 404

Comment: @Channa you should not put the whole URL in the hostname field. It is called: hostname, not URL ;-) The idea is to be able to override 'localhost' to something like: my.localhost.bla then it will use that instead of localhost. In your case the host field needs to be localhost. You set the port to 8080 and configure the redirect to go to: tolocalhost.com/dashboard/twitterRedirect.jsp this will redirect to: localhost:8080/dashboard/twitterRedirect.jsp

Answer (score 1):

set callbackurl in twitter app  : 127.0.0.1:3000
and set WEBrick to bind on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

command : rails s -b 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Twitter now allows `localhost` alongside whatever you have in the `Callback URL` settings, so long as there is a value there.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and followed a dozen solutions, in the end all I had to do to work with any ssl apis on local host was:

Go download: [cacert.pem file](https://codeload.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/zip/master)

In `php.ini` * un-comment and change: 

`curl.cainfo = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/cacert.pem"`

- You can find where your `php.ini` file is on your machine by running `php --ini` in your CLI
- I placed my cacert.pem in the same directory as php.ini for ease.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that worked for me to get Facebook working with a local application on my laptop:

- goto `apps.twitter.com`
- enter the name, app description and your site URL
  Note: for `localhost:8000`, use `127.0.0.1:8000` since the former will not work
- enter the callback URL matching your callback URL defined in TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI your application
  Note: eg: `http://127.0.0.1/login/twitter/callback` (localhost will not work).
- *Important* enter both the "privacy policy" and "terms of use" URLs if you wish to request the user's email address
- check the agree to terms checkbox
- click [Create Your Twitter Application]
- switch to the [Keys and Access Tokens] tab at the top
- copy the "Consumer Key (API Key)" and "Consumer Secret (API Secret)" to TWITTER_KEY and TWITTER_SECRET in your application
- click the "Permissions" tab and set appropriately to "read only", "read and write" or "read, write and direct message" (use the least intrusive option needed for your application, for just and OAuth login "read only" is sufficient
- Under "Additional Permissions" check the "request email addresses from users" checkbox if you wish for the user's email address to be returned to the OAuth login data (in most cases check yes)