# JTwitter OAuth with callback authorisation

Tags: java, twitter, callback, oauth, jtwitter

I am writing an App using JTwitter however I need to authenticate in order to not have the 150 requests per minute on the public api.

Jtwitter seems to support OAuth however I have some questions.

My app will be running behind a company firewall - so the URL wont be accessible outside of the company's network - will callback authorisation work, and does anybody have an example of using callback authorisation using OAuth in JTwitter - because I cannot work it out in order to try it.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter won't access the callback URI directly. As part of the OAuth workflow, the user is sent to twitter.com to notify Twitter that they grant your app the right to access their account. The callback URL is a location to which the client is redirected after they are done interacting directly with twitter.

So theoretically, when you're developing, the callback URL could even be off of 127.0.0.1: [Twitter oAuth callbackUrl - localhost development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800827/twitter-oauth-callbackurl-localhost-development)

This tutorial explains things pretty well: http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-ii-protocol-workflow/