# Google OAuth2 not working on local development server - PHP Codeigniter spark

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am trying to use the Codeigniter spark 
( http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show) 
to allow users to login to my php site with fb and google.

My local dev site (on wampserver) is called mysite.dev, for which I have a etc/hosts file like :

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.dev
```

Facebook login works absolutely fine. But when I try logging with google, google complains :
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://mysite.dev/index.php/oauth2/session/google
where oauth2 is my controller and session is the function where I specify fb/google, etc

any clues/hints?

Comment: Have a similar issue here as well, any good workaround as I can not use localhost, but rather need a custom domain name like: project.company. I would rather not go changing all the developers hostnames to project.company.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oauth - how to test with local urls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456174/oauth-how-to-test-with-local-urls)

Answer (score 20):

I got around this by adding a hosts file record for the domain with the dev part at the front rather than the end (which I usually do too):

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.mydomain.com
```

/etc/apache vhost

```
ServerName mydomain.com.localhost
ServerAlias localhost.mydomain.com
```

Then tell google to use:

```
http://localhost.mydomain.com/index.php/oauth2/session/google
```

Answer (score 8):

When you create client ID for web applications in Google APIs Console you can add allowed `Redirect URIs`. It accepts `localhost` urls and others as well.

Comment: Google accepts localhost, but not custom domain like example.somecustomtopleveldomain

Which is kind of shame, because if you have multiple web projects, you usually assign custom domain name, like project1.something which does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Google API Console does not allow 'mysite.dev'.

Answer (score 5):

Adding

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.mydomain.com
```

to my `hosts` file and

```
http://localhost.mydomain.com/oauth2callback
```

to "Authorized redirect URIs" worked for me

Comment: This worked for me. In Laravel, you also need to add it to your Homestead.yaml file like so `- map: localhost.mydomain.com
      to: /home/vagrant/your-path-here/mydomain/public` and then provision

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run the OAuth process **once** on your dev site, there is a quick workaround.

Login to your Google Cloud Console, visit APIs & Services⁩ ▸ Credentials ⁩ ▸ OAuth 2.0 Client IDs ⁩ ▸ Authorised Redirect URIs and a New URI with the following value:

```
http://localhost/index.php/oauth2/session/google
```

Then navigate to your dev site using **localhost** rather than **mysite.dev** as the domain. Go through the OAuth process on localhost. Google should now accept your return URI. Once successfully authorised, you can go back to using mysite.dev.