# callback url is not working in twitter for localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am using twitter login with asp.net.callback url not worked for local host.I have tried every solution i found on google.But still same problem.

IS THIS POSSIBLE TO USE CALLBACK URL LOCALHOST?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions listed in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800827/twitter-oauth-callbackurl-localhost-development)?

Comment: tried everything...is it woked for localhost??

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use localhost u need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

for example

```
http://127.0.0.1:youportnumber
```