# creating a twitter project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter

I am trying to create an MVC4 project that is going to read tweets using the streaming api. I am facing a challenge when im an trying to get an appId and appSecret. I am getting this error: "Error
The client application failed validation: Not a valid URL format
The client application failed validation: Not a valid URL format" when i am specifying my localhost address as my website and callback url. Please help.

This is how i am typing-in my URL http://localhost:50470/ still it does not work. I also tried this  https://localhost:50470/

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800827/twitter-oauth-callbackurl-localhost-development

Comment: Got it, its supposed to be https://localhost.com

Comment: If you do that you'll have to configure the hosts on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

need to put in both the website and the callback URL the same domain value

Ex

Website:
http://127.0.0.1

Callback URL:
http://127.0.0.1/api