# how can I connect 127.0.0.1 on Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to set up Twitter OmniAuth on Ruby on rails. However, I got a Forbidden error.

The reason is:

```
"Cannot render console from 10.240.1.191! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, "
```

on my terminal.

How can I connect 'networks: 127.0.0.1'??

[Twitter settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNLxl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is described by https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitter-api/issues/534#c1. And [a (decent score) answer here at so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800827/twitter-oauth-callbackurl-localhost-development), should also fix/workaround/solve your problem. (possible duplicate!?)